# Connecting to a local MySQL server

Tags: mysql, windows, networking, connection, mysql-workbench

I would be grateful if someone could provide some help on how to connect to a local MySQL server (computer) from my laptop which is on the same local network.

1. I downloaded/installed MySQL on Windows (Installer & Tools) on the laptop and computer and I think they're both up and running.
2. When I try to 'create a connection' on my laptop within MySQL Workbench, I just can't seem to connect and I've tried various usernames and passwords.  Do I need to configure the settings on the desktop server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key word is "think".  You need to know that the server is up.

Open a command shell and type "netstat -a".  You'll see every listener on every port.

If you see that something's LISTENING on port 3306, then it's most likely MySQL.

If port 3306 doesn't appear, you have your answer.

You need to know that the listener is running on the database machine you'd like to connect to.

Once you ascertain that the listener is up and running, you need to know that your client has been GRANTed permission to connect via username and password.  Only the DA for the database can set that up and let you know.

Comment: MySQL is running as a Windows service on both the laptop and computer and if I type "netstat -a" in command prompt on the laptop, it's listening on port 3306.

Comment: "both laptop and computer" - which one are you trying to connect to?

Comment: the computer (192.168.0.6). When I try to setup a new connection on MySQL Workbench on the laptop, in setting up the remote management type and target operating system settings, I get asked to enter a user and password as shown here(http://i60.tinypic.com/287iucw.jpg).  Having tried various combinations, I receive an error "Could not set up connection. Could not connect to target machine."

Comment: It actually works. I was actually receiving an error message when trying to set up remote management (which I don't actually need/want at the moment). Thanks.